# Rails, Paperclip options. Pass multiple options as one parameter to paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a model with an attached file using Paperclip. It is described with multiple parameters:

```
has_attached_file :attachment,
  styles: {
    regular: Proc.new { |instance| instance.detect_regular_style },
    thumb: '144x144>'
  },
  storage: :s3,
  s3_protocol: :https
  ...
```

Can I somehow merge these all parameters to one variable(lambda or similar thing) so that I could reuse them to an other attachment?
The code I imagine could look like this (this one does not read the options passed):

```
has_attached_file :attachment, {options: -> {attached_file_options} }
has_attached_file :picture, {options: -> {attached_file_options} }

def attached_file_options
{
  styles: {
    regular: Proc.new { |instance| instance.detect_regular_style },
    thumb: '144x144>'
  },
  storage: :s3,
  s3_protocol: :https
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer was simple: just a variable with the hash of parameters. Remember to assign data to variable before accessing it:

```
ATTACHED_FILE_OPTIONS =
  {
    styles: {
      regular: Proc.new { |instance| instance.detect_regular_style },
      thumb: '144x144>'
    },
    storage: :s3,
    s3_protocol: :https
    ...
  }

has_attached_file :attachment, ATTACHED_FILE_OPTIONS
has_attached_file :picture, ATTACHED_FILE_OPTIONS
```